# chrome leaves extra space after css transform

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-transforms, translate

chrome leaves extra space after transformation.

to reproduce issue:
switch on responsive mode (for example take iphone 5/SE)
because of element x position + element width is greater then viewport with the horizontal scrollbar will appear. its ok but the thing is when u click the button "update transformation" (it will just update/transforms the element x position) after that there is no need for extra space or horizontal scrollbar but seems chrome doesn't updates a viewport size. (in this example width is a same after transformation).

P.S. it works correctly in FF

```
<h2>test transform</h2>


<a href="/" class="hp-section-image-zebra">
<img src="https://uploads- ssl.webflow.com/5a7bafaa69f239000170771c/5a7e5dcdd2e04c0001f3fcdc_desktop.png" alt="Refurbished Apple Desktops">
</a>

<button onclick="updateTransformation()">update transformation</button>



<style>
    body{
        border: solid black;
    }
    .hp-section-image-zebra{
        display: inline-block;
        transform: translate(300px, 0px);
    }
</style>

<script>
    function updateTransformation() {
        var el = document.querySelector('body > a');
        el.style.transform="translateX(0px)";
    }
</script>
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyvNXJ?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

Use this css for all browsers:

```css
.hp-section-image-zebra{
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: translate(300px, 0px);
       -moz-transform: translate(300px, 0px);
        -ms-transform: translate(300px, 0px);
         -o-transform: translate(300px, 0px);
            transform: translate(300px, 0px);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't make any effect.